# Powershell script in VSTS Build Definition not updating AssemblyVersion.cs

Tags: powershell, azure-devops, devops, azure-pipelines, build-definition

I have a Project hosted in VSTS and I'm experimenting with the Build Definitions. I'm trying to execute a powershell script that updates the AssemblyVersion.cs before the Project is built. When I run the script locally it works fine, but when it's ran during the Build process, the script runs without error, but the AssemblyVersion.cs is not updated.

```
$regex = '\[assembly: AssemblyVersion\("(.*)"\)\]'
$assemblyInfoPath = "..\Properties\AssemblyInfo.cs"

(Get-Content $assemblyInfoPath) | ForEach-Object {
    if($_ -match $regex) 
    {
        # Get current version, and update revision number
        $version = [version]$matches[1]
        $newVersion = "{0}.{1}.{2}.{3}" -f $version.Major, $version.Minor, $version.Build, ($version.Revision + 1)
        '[assembly: AssemblyVersion("{0}")]' -f $newVersion

        Write-Host "Version updated to: $newVersion"
    } 
    else 
    {
        $_
    }
} | Set-Content $assemblyInfoPath
```

The Build output states that the version has been updated, but when I view AssemblyInfo.cs in the File Viewer it shows the old version.

Comment: Which file viewer are you talking about? The one from source control? The one for the artefacts? Or the windows explorer on the build machine?

Comment: @baywet The source control file viewer

Comment: Do you solve the issue now?

Answer (score 0):

The build process doesn't check in/commit changes made to source code automatically at the end of the process. You have to write a script to do that.

Answer (score 0):

You need to checkin or push changes to remote repository.

If you are using TFVC, there is [TFVC Build Tasks extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=jessehouwing.jessehouwing-vsts-tfvc-tasks) that includes TFVC-Check-in Changes step/task that can check in changes.

If you are using Git, you can add these steps/tasks to push changes:

1. Command Line (Tool: `git`; Arguments: `add **\*.*;` Working folder: `$(build.sourcesdirectory))`
2. Command Line (Tool: `git`; Arguments: `commit -m "update";` Working folder: `$(build.sourcesdirectory))`
3. Command Line (Tool: git; Arguments: `push origin HEAD:$(Build.SourceBranchName)`; Working folder: `$(build.sourcesdirectory))`

On the other hand, you also could build a custom build/release task and use it in your build/release. More information about custom build/release task, you can refer to: [Add a build task](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/integrate/extensions/develop/add-build-task)

Note: It is not recommended to checkin/push changes to the remote repository in build or release.